# Symmetric Matrix Equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $$A = I - AB$$

Prove that if $B = B^t$ then $A = A^t$ (when t is transpose).

How can I prove that? I played with it alot but couldn't find a way to solve it.

EDIT: 
I also already proved that $$AB=BA$$ if that helps.

Comment: If you've proved that $AB$ is symmetric, then you're almost there. If $AB$ is symmetric, what does that say about $I-AB$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A=I-AB$ implies that $A+AB=I$, or equivalently, 
$$A(I+B)=I.$$
Therefore, $A$ is invertible and $A^{-1}=(I+B)^{-1}$. 
Therefore, if $B=B^T$, i.e. $B$ is symmetric, 
then $A^{-1}$ is also symmetric. If $A^{-1}$ is symmetric, then $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: Can't believe that I missed that.. after that I already prove that $A^{-1} = (I+B)$.. Thanks!